# authentication with google in next.js app and deploy on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, frontend

I am trying to add authentication with google in my next.js app and deploy it on netlify,
in dev mode I got desired result but when I deploy it on netlify I got server error,
I am using next-auth library

I tried to change setting in my google cloud api service But still it does not work.
how should I change setting?
[image]

Comment: Are you using purely client-side code for this, or are you using the server-side login flow? If the latter, then you will of course have to add a proper redirect URI for your "live app" as well.

Comment: I am using next-auth library

Comment: Since https://next-auth.js.org/providers/facebook refers to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/, I am guessing that means server-side flow then.